# Remove a URL Card in a Tweet (API)

Tags: node.js, twitter

I am using the API to post tweets automatically (npm "twitter"). The tweet contains a URL and twitter automatically transforms it into a Card. I want to remove the Card and only see the URL.

Example: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter automatically does this for web pages where the target site has card meta tags. You’ll either have to find a URL that does not have card meta data, or use a Twitter client application that does not render cards.